# Why are linked lists stored in the heap and not the stack?

Tags: linked-list, heap-memory, stack-memory

I've always been taught to use linked lists with the heap, but I don't understand why exactly you can't just use it with the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposition is in fact false; linked lists are not only stored on the stack, but there is often a linked list being maintained as part of a run-time stack: that's how we are able to obtain a call trace. Call traces are possible due to a linked list of frame pointers, chained through the call stack.

A linked list can consist of nodes that are each in the stack of a different execution context (like a thread). There is an operating system technique of putting a task to sleep in a wait queue by declaring a linked list node on that thread's stack, and enqueuing that into a wait queue directly.

Comment: Then why is it that in every programming example, linked lists are usually used with Node* tmp = new Node?

Comment: @Bob Because the examples are elementary, and not a full exploration about every angle and use scenario involving linked lists. Dynamic memory is easy to understand; none of the nodes allocated with `new Node` will abruptly go away unless `delete` is explicitly used on them.